# Extend MultiLineRule (or similar) to stop on one of two tokens

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm looking to contribute to an eclipse plugin project whose aim is to provide an editor for Cucumber/Gherkin languages (specifically, cucumber-jvm).  This editor is using JFace to render the editor.

I see in the project that org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.RuleBasedPartitionScanner is extended to separate the gherkin file into its constituent parts.  The rules that do this are extended from org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.MultiLineRule.

MultiLineRule is an extension of org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.PatternRule that looks for a startSequence and endSequence.  The problem I am encountering is that I want to look for an endSequence that can be one of two things ("Scenario" or "Background").

Any ideas for how to implement this?  I'm a bit of an eclipse plugin newbie but would like to learn :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's a regExPattern it's `Scenario|Background`

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a regex, at least based on the code in PatternRule (the base class for MultiLineRule)